# Kentico Migration Update URLs

Tags: url, kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc

I have recently inherited a Kentico site and there still seems to be links to the old owner's instance. Is there a way in Kentico to update links and URLs?

I've searched through the codebase for traces of the URL but cannot find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find where to do this.

You need to update the Site domain name and Presentation URL fields in Kentico. 
These can be found under:
Configuration > Sites > Your site